pandas csv to object list is slow
I have a data file like the following (simplified, I have more columns):




timestamp
frame_idx
gaze_pos_x
gaze_pos_y
gaze_dir_x
gaze_dir_y
gaze_dir_z




0
2269.17
45
893.314
500.136
0.165454
-0.0222454
0.985967


1
2274.17
45
896.61
502.564
0.176397
-0.0098666
0.98427


2
2279.17
46
900.592
499.049
0.189087
-0.018215
0.981791


3
2284.17
46
906.321
478.184
0.18891
-0.0307506
0.981513


4
2289.17
46
893.465
502.793
0.175493
-0.0210113
0.984257


5
2294.17
46
898.629
497.182
0.190142
-0.0151722
0.981639


6
2299.3
46
893.554
496.782
0.183007
-0.0150504
0.982996


7
2304.3
46
905.338
482.343
0.188236
-0.0249608
0.981807


8
2309.3
46
897.44
495.476
0.187434
-0.0199951
0.982074


9
2424.3
48
893.358
495.474
0.171512
-0.0198278
0.984982



And an object like this (again simplified):
class Gaze:
    def __init__(self, ts, frame_idx, gaze2D, gaze_dir3D=None):
        self.ts = ts
        self.frame_idx = frame_idx
        self.gaze2D = gaze2D
        self.gaze_dir3D = gaze_dir3D

where gaze2D is a numpy array containing [gaze_pos_x, gaze_pos_y] and gaze_dir3D is a numpy array containing [gaze_dir_x, gaze_dir_y, gaze_dir_z].
I want to efficiently load in the data file and make one Gaze object per row. I have implemented the below, but this is very slow:
def readDataFromFile(fileName):
    gazes   = []
    data    = pd.read_csv(str(fileName), delimiter='\t', index_col=False, dtype=defaultdict(lambda: float, frame_idx=int))
    allCols = tuple([c for c in data.columns if col in c] for col in (
        'gaze_pos','gaze_dir'))
    # allCols -> ([gaze_pos_x, gaze_pos_y],[gaze_dir_x, gaze_dir_y, gaze_dir_z]), a list can be empty if a set of columns is missing (gaze_dir is optional)

    # run through all rows
    for _, row in data.iterrows():
        frame_idx = int(row['frame_idx'])  # must cast to int as pd.Series seems to lose typing of dataframe.... :s
        ts        = row['timestamp']

        # get all values (None if columns not present)
        # again need to cast to float despite all items in the series being a float, because the dtype of the series is object... :s
        args = tuple(row[c].astype('float').to_numpy() if c else None for c in allCols)
        gazes.append(Gaze(ts, frame_idx, *args))
    return gazes

As said, this is very slow, the row iteration takes forever, it is prohibitively slow for my use case. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Using a similar read-in function using a csv.DictReader is a little faster but still way too slow.

Well, iterating over rows of a dataframe will always be much slower in pandas. You should try to vectorize your code if it's possible.

@MGP, yeah, i have read this. I don't see how to vectorize this...

Posting the question and being implored to vectorize gave me new inspiration. Here's a fast solution!
def readDataFromFile(fileName):
    df = pd.read_csv(str(fileName), delimiter='\t', index_col=False, dtype=defaultdict(lambda: float, frame_idx=int))

    # group columns into numpy arrays, insert None if missing
    cols = ('gaze_pos','gaze_dir')
    allCols = tuple([c for c in df.columns if col in c] for col in cols)
    for c,ac in zip(cols,allCols):
        if ac:
            df[c] = [x for x in df[ac].values]  # make list of numpy arrays
        else:
            df[c] = None

    # clean up so we can assign into gaze objects directly
    lookup = {'timestamp':'ts'} | {k:v for k,v in zip(cols,['gaze2D','gaze_dir3D'])}
    df = df.drop(columns=[c for c in df.columns if c not in lookup.keys() and c!='frame_idx'])
    df = df.rename(columns=lookup)

    # make the gaze objects
    gazes = [Gaze(**kwargs) for kwargs in df.to_dict(orient='records')]

    return gazes


If you want to more squeeze performance I recommend to not use pandas but load the lines and convert them manually, e.g.:
class Gaze:
    def __init__(self, ts, frame_idx, gaze2D, gaze_dir3D=None):
        self.ts = ts
        self.frame_idx = frame_idx
        self.gaze2D = gaze2D
        self.gaze_dir3D = gaze_dir3D

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Gaze(ts={self.ts}, frame_idx={self.frame_idx}, gaze2D={self.gaze2D}, gaze_dir3D={self.gaze_dir3D})"


all_data = []
with open("your_data.csv", "r") as f_in:
    next(f_in)  # skip headers
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if not line:  # skip empty lines
            continue

        (
            timestamp,
            frame_idx,
            gaze_pos_x,
            gaze_pos_y,
            gaze_dir_x,
            gaze_dir_y,
            gaze_dir_z,
        ) = line.split("\t")

        all_data.append(
            Gaze(
                float(timestamp),
                int(frame_idx),
                (float(gaze_pos_x), float(gaze_pos_y)),
                (float(gaze_dir_x), float(gaze_dir_y), float(gaze_dir_z)),
            )
        )

print(all_data)

Prints:
[
    Gaze(
        ts=2269.17,
        frame_idx=45,
        gaze2D=(893.314, 500.136),
        gaze_dir3D=(0.165454, -0.0222454, 0.985967),
    ),
    Gaze(
        ts=2274.17,
        frame_idx=45,
        gaze2D=(896.61, 502.564),
        gaze_dir3D=(0.176397, -0.0098666, 0.98427),
    ),
    Gaze(
        ts=2279.17,
        frame_idx=46,
        gaze2D=(900.592, 499.049),
        gaze_dir3D=(0.189087, -0.018215, 0.981791),
    ),

...

